# IIS, SSL, and Virtual Directories

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, iis-6

I'm running a webserver on WS 2k3, IIS 6.0.  Some of the content is on that server, but most is in a virtual directory linked to another server.  Everything works (almost) fine when no SSL is used.  However, when using SSL, I cannot access the files in the virtual directory.  Instead I get error 404, page not found.

IIS log of the requests:

```
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status 

[date] W3SVC116779885 192.168.168.35 GET /logo.gif - 443 - [my ip] Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_6_3;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/531.22.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0+Safari/531.9 401 2 2148074254

[date] W3SVC116779885 192.168.168.35 GET /logo.gif - 443 - [my ip] [ua] 401 1 0

[date] W3SVC116779885 192.168.168.35 GET /logo.gif - 443 TS1\ipad [ip] [ua] 200 0 0

[date] W3SVC116779885 192.168.168.35 GET /patients/1118.pdf - 443 - [ip] [ua] 500 16 1326
```

Note that logo is in the main server, while patients is the virtual directory.

Any advice?

Comment: the past line which shows the status 500 16 1326, 
1326 means Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

make sure you have good username and password configured on the virtual directory Connect As.. or if you are using "Pass through authentication", make sure the users who are trying to connect have Read and Execute permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your are getting when try to access `/patients/1118.pdf` is a 500.16. This means "UNC authorization credentials are incorrect" in IIS world.

Check to make sure that the user you are connecting to the share with has proper permissions on the destination server/path.

Comment: Thank you!  For some reason the authentication password reset when I set up SSL, and I didn't notice until you told me where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Have any IIS Logs you can share?  Sort of hard to diagnose without detailed information or event viewer messages that may point to a problem.

Comment: I left it as an answer below for formatting purposes.  Thanks.  :)